# Does "雑用" really describe ”俺” here in this context?

Tags: translation

Read it on this novel. https://ncode.syosetu.com/n6012eu/292/

> "って言っても、俺は雑用みたいなものだけど"

I'm pretty sure it doesn't mean "I'm something like a chore/miscellaneous expenses."

Does this just mean "I'm on/spending miscellaneous expenses​."?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> だからこその調査任務。というわけで（冒険学部の長にコネを持つ）俺にも協力要請が飛んで来たのだ。
>
> （って言っても、俺は雑用みたいなものだけど）

In this context, 「雑用{ざつよう}」 would be synonymous to 「雑用係{ざつようがかり}」.

> "Even so, I'll be more like a handy-andy."

To be completely honest, I have no idea how you get "expenses".

Comment: It was on every dictionary I found. 
https://jisho.org/search/雑用
Is this similar to "gofer"? 
I've never heard Handy Andy used before.

Comment: "gofer", "handyman", etc.  The meaning "miscellaneous expenses​" only applies in the context of accounting.  In Japanese, context is king.